# Sorting algoritm

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, sorting

I want to make my algorithm more efficient via deleting the items it already sorted, but i don't know how I can do it efficiently. The only way I found was to rewrite the whole list.

```
l = [] #Here you put your list
sl = [] # this is to store the list when it is sorted
a = 0 # variable to store which numbers he already looked for
while True: # loop
    if len(sl) == len(l): #if their size is matching it will stop
        print(sl) # print the sorted list
        break
    a = a + 1 
    if a in l: # check if it is in list
        sl.append(a) # add to sorted list
#here i want it to be deleted from the list.
```

Comment: There are much better ways to sort a list. Just do a little search.

Comment: This algorithm does not sort *at all*. It merely filters the natural numbers by residency in a list; it fails for non-integers, negative numbers and duplicates. Are you looking for a) adding deletion to this filtering, b) making this filtering more efficient or c) making an efficient sorting algorithm?

Comment: `sl = sorted(l)`, which has the benefit of terminating even if the input list does not consist solely of unique positive numbers.

Comment: Actually, it does sort the list assuming the list consists only of distinct natural numbers. It will return a wrong result if the list contains duplicates, negative numbers, or non-integers.

Comment: @Stef I don't think it terminates unless the input list consists of unique positive numbers. The termination condition is `len(sl) == len(l)`.

Comment: @Paul Hankin I do think you and I agree on this. We're using different words but basically saying the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `a` is a little awkward. It starts at 0 and increments 1 by 1 until it matches elements from the list `l`

Imagine if `l = [1000000, 1200000, -34]`. Then your algorithm will first run for 1000000 iterations without doing anything, just incrementing `a` from 0 to 1000000. Then it will append 1000000 to `sl`. Then it will run again 200000 iterations without doing anything, just incrementing `a` from 1000000 to 1200000.

And then it will keep incrementing `a` looking for the number -34, which is below zero...

I understand the idea behind your variable `a` is to select the elements from `l` in order, starting from the smallest element. There is a function that does that: it's called `min()`. Try using that function to select the smallest element from `l`, and append that element to `sl`. Then delete this element from `l`; otherwise, the next call to `min()` will select the same element again instead of selecting the next smallest element.

Note that `min()` has a disadvantage: it returns the value of the smallest element, but not its position in the list. So it's not completely obvious how to delete the element from `l` after you've found it with `min()`. An alternative is to write your own function that returns both the element, and its position. You can do that with one loop: in the following piece of code, `i` refers to a position in the list (0 is the position of the first element, 1 the position of the second, etc) and `a` refers to the value of that element. I left blanks and you have to figure out how to select the position and value of the smallest element in the list.

```
....
for i, a in enumerate(l):
    if ...:
        ...
...
```

If you managed to do all this, congratulations! You have implemented "selection sort". It's a well-known sorting algorithm. It is one of the simplest. There exist many other sorting algorithms.